# Are arrow keys detected by FFI-NCurses in Ruby 1.9.2 on Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, ncurses

I am writing a tiny text editor using FFI-NCurses in Ruby 1.9.2 on Windows 7 (64-bit). After setting the keypad mode, I am able to handle the function keys. However, NCurses does not detect arrow keys being pressed.

I have a multimedia keyboard configured on Windows 7 as a normal US keyboard. Googling shows that arrow keys should have been detected once I set keypad mode to TRUE, but it just does not work.

Are the Ruby bindings at fault, or does NCurses on Windows (7) has a known issue of being unable to detect arrow keys?